# Deny permissions to execute PowerShell Get-AzAutomationCertificate

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-automation

I am trying to create a custom reader role on Azure that does not allow the user to run the PowerShell command Get-AzAutomationCertificate. I have gone through the options and removed quite a few permissions related to reading certificates from the automation service provider. However, it appears it is still not enough.

These are the deny options present in the custom role :

```
"notActions": [
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/listKeys/action",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/certificates/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/certificates/getCount/action",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/jobs/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/jobs/runbookContent/action",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/credentials/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks/content/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/python2Packages/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/python3Packages/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/privateEndpointConnectionProxies/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/connections/read",
 "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/connectionTypes/read
]
```

[image: Visual Description]

More details about the command :
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/Automation/Automation/help/Get-AzAutomationCertificate.md

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would like to clarify that the `NotActions` permission specifies the management operations that are excluded from the allowed `Actions`. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-definitions#notactions).

So if the Action is not included in `Actions`, it's unnecessary to put it into `NotActions` in order to make it lose effectiveness. In this case, the user will not have the permission to do the action.

The action "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/certificates/read" is what you want to make the PowerShell command `Get-AzAutomationCertificate` effective. Please note that it allows `Get-AzAutomationCertificate` to be executed but won't return results.

Here is my example:

```
{
  "Name": "Custom Role 2",
  "Id": null,
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "Don't allow for Get-AzAutomationCertificate",
  "Actions": [
  "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/certificates/read",
  "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/read"
  ],
  "NotActions": [
  "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/certificates/read"
  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/{subscription id}"
  ]
}
```

Please pay attention to the note in above link:

> If a user is assigned a role that excludes an operation in NotActions,
>   and is assigned a second role that grants access to the same
>   operation, the user is allowed to perform that operation. NotActions
>   is not a deny rule – it is simply a convenient way to create a set of
>   allowed operations when specific operations need to be excluded.

After you update the custom role and assign it to the user, you should reopen an PowerShell window and re-login with the user. Then it will work for you.